# Django filter listview by url parameter not working

Tags: django, django-views

**I'm trying to filter the result of a ListView through a URL parameter but it is not working. What the webapp does is that in a session, many pictures can be saved, so the idea is through a search bar you can filter the sessions and see its pictures.
I have tried using in the ListView which uses two models that are linked through a foreign key, the postgresql search lookup but it does not filter**

> views.py

```
class SessionPictures(generic.ListView):

    model = PostSession
    template_name = 'photoadmin/gallery.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SessionPictures, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['picture'] = Images.objects.filter(
            name__session_name__search='search')
        return context
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('upload', views.UploadView.as_view(), name='upload'),
    path('gallery/<search>/', views.SessionPictures.as_view(), name='gallery')

]
```

> models.py

```
class PostSession(models.Model):
    session_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.session_name)


class Images(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(
        PostSession, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')
```

**The idea is to filter the sessions. I don't get an error, it just don´t filter.**

Comment: What is`name__session_name__search` supposed to do? Apart from that, you are trying to filter by the string literal `'search'`. If you want to access the path argument named `search` you should `pop` it from `kwargs`. Please read the Django documentation for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it all wrong.

1. `Images.objects.filter(name__session_name__search='search')` will search for for word "search" in `PostSession.session_name` using [full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) (`__search` part).
2. Putting the search term in url `gallery/<search>/'` might work but usually we are using [urlparams](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) like `gallery/?search=django`

```
class SessionPictures(generic.ListView):

    model = PostSession
    template_name = 'photoadmin/gallery.html'

    def get_qeryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        search_term = self.request.GET.get("search", None)
        if search_term is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(session_name__icontains=search_term)
        return qs
```

```
path('gallery/', views.SessionPictures.as_view(), name='gallery')
```

With such setup you can just make a request:

`GET gallery/?search=python`

and the view will populate the context with [context object name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name) `postsession_list`